# Autocomplete Pandoc-style citations from a Bibtex file in Emacs

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, markdown, bibtex, pandoc

### Pandoc-style citations

[Pandoc](http://www.johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) uses a Markdown format that supports automatic citations using keys from BibTeX files. Some examples for the format are:

`Blah blah [@doe99]`

`Blah blah [@doe99, p.33]`

`Blah blah [see @doe99, pp. 33-35; also @smith04, ch. 1].`

### Emacs and Pandoc/Markdown

There is a [Pandoc-Mode](http://wwwuser.gwdg.de/~jkremer/pandoc-mode.html) for interacting with Pandoc through Emacs which can be combined with [Markdown-Mode](http://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode/). Pandoc-Mode and Markdown-Mode don't support autocompletion of citations from bibtex files. A mode that has this kind of support for TeX files is [Reftex](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/reftex.html). I am looking for a way to get Reftex-style autocompletion when editing Markdown files.

### Autocompletion in other editors

There is a solution for Textmate: [Autocomplete pandoc-style citations from a bibtex file in textmate](http://snipplr.com/view/19519/).

The feature is also in [Vim-Pandoc](https://github.com/vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc):

> Autocompletion was implemented by hacking away at [LaTeX Box's](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3109)
>   implementation of bibtex citation completion, even if the results
>   don't look much like the original.

## How can I get autocompletion for pandoc-style citations from a bibtex file in Emacs?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To do this you can use `reftex-citation`.

### Setup

#### Enable RefTeX

You have to enable RefTeX for the file you are editing which can be done via `M-x reftex-mode` or by setting a [file variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html) such as adding `-*- mode: reftex; -*-` to the first line of the file.

#### Tell RefTeX where you bibliography is

You need to tell RefTeX [where your bibliography file is](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54825/5701). This can be done by adding the following to your .emacs (and editing the path according to your setup):

```lisp
;; So that RefTeX finds my bibliography
(setq reftex-default-bibliography '("path/to/bibfile.bib"))
```

Note that `reftex-default-bibliography` is a list, so you can add several paths to it.

If you use different bibliographies for different files it might be preferable to tell RefTeX of the bibliography from each file. I am afraid I only know of an ugly way to do this. The idea is that since RefTeX can extract the correct bibliography from LaTeX macros you can embed a LaTeX macro in a comment. Thus, you can add such a comment along with the specification of bibliography to Pandoc:

```
bibliography::bibliography_name.bib
<!-- \bibliography{bibliography_name} So that RefTeX knows about the bibliography -->
```

#### Tell RefTeX how to format citations

To get `reftex-citation` to insert in the format used by Pandoc you have to customize [`reftex-cite-format`](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/reftex/reftex_60.html) such as inserting the following into your .emacs:

```lisp
(eval-after-load 'reftex-vars
  '(progn 
     (setq reftex-cite-format '((?\C-m . "[@%l]")))))
```

You may wan to include other formats too. For instructions on how to do this see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31992/5701. Note that this setting is global so that if you also use RefTeX for LaTeX it will also be affected.

### Use

To insert a citation either do `M-x reftex-citation` or `C-c [` then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and you are allowed to insert a search term for searching in your bibliography. RefTeX will then insert the key of the bibliography item you selected in Pandoc format.

Comment: This works, but I can't change `reftex-default-bibliography` for each file that has a different bibliography. Each file has a settings file `.filename.latex.pandoc` which includes a line `bibliography::/path/to/bibtexfile.bib`. Can Reftex automatically load the Bibtex file from the settings file?

Comment: @lecodesportif It seems that customizing `reftex-bibliography-commands` as described in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54825/5701 won't work as `bibliography::/path/to/bibtexfile.bib` is not in LaTeX format. How are comments formatted in Pandoc? Maybe you could specify the bibliography via a commented LaTeX macro or . You could also add more paths to `reftex-default-bibliography` as it is a list. You might also be able to this file local via a file variable.

Comment: Pandoc Markdown uses HTML comments `<!-- ... -->`. How would Reftex retrieve the bib file path from the comments? The cleanest way might be to have some Emacs Lisp code get the bib file name from the [Pandoc-Mode settings file](http://wwwuser.gwdg.de/~jkremer/pandoc-mode-manual.html#settings-files) and pass it to Reftex.

Comment: @lecodesportif Embedding a LaTeX macro to tell RefTeX where the bibliography is seems to work (added to my answer). I am afraid that other than this adding a list of the bibliographies you want to use with RefTeX is the best I can come up with at the moment as I am not sure how to fetch the bibliography from a Pandoc file and I am not how to tell RefTeX of a file local bibliography.

Comment: You can also directly bind `reftex-citation` to `C-c [` in the markdown mode hook, as suggested [in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/reftex/Citations-Outside-LaTeX.html#SEC31). That shows how to use a local definition for `reftex-cite-format` (and by analogy `reftex-default-bibliography`), too.